# Facebook login without a form

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

How can I log into Facebook without a login form?

I've created an application which posts wall posts to one of my pages automatically (with a cron job).

But it needs login. I've done everything with the PHP SDK 3.1 and it works if I am logged into Facebook by my browser. But it does not work on my hosting and this is important for me because it is "scheduled auto poster".

Is it possible with the PHP SDK or JavaScript SDK or anything?

PS: Logging in with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) does not work (code: `http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/290893`).

I use PHP SDK 3.1.

Here is my code:

```
 require 'sdk/facebook.php';
      $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $bilgi_appID,
      'secret' => $bilgi_appSecret,
      'fileUpload' => true,
      'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support
    ));
      $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$args = array(
    'message' => $bilgi_fotoMesaji,
    "access_token" => $access_token,
    "image" => $file
);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$bilgi_sayfaninAlbumIDsi.'/photos', 'post', $args);
if ($data) 
    print_r("basariyla yuklendi...");
```

This works when I am logged in Facebook.

But how can I post a photo or post while I am logged out? It redirects login page.

Comment: As long as you use API - you should never simulate real user login (which, in fact, is illegal). How do you post? What permissions did you get?

Comment: I use php sdk 3.1

here are my codes

 `require 'sdk/facebook.php';
      $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $bilgi_appID,
      'secret' => $bilgi_appSecret,
      'fileUpload' => true,
      'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support
    ));
      $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$args = array(
    'message' => $bilgi_fotoMesaji,
    "access_token" => $access_token,
    "image" => $file
);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$bilgi_sayfaninAlbumIDsi.'/photos', 'post', $args);
if ($data) print_r("basariyla yuklendi...");`

This works when i logged in facebook.

Comment: you better put that to the original question

Comment: also i have manage_pages,offline_access and wall posts auth. for that page. but it redirects me login page when i clicked while i am not logged in.

Comment: `also i have manage_pages,offline_access and wall posts auth` -- you only need `publish_stream` permission to post to a user's feed. And I don't understand what `It redirects login page.` means - because the code you've shown just cannot redirect

Comment: I upload a photo to one of my pages. (not user wall, page wall).

Comment: this is the adress which it redirects:

`https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=my_api_key&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=my_url%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D345052285533166%26redirect_uri%3Dmy_url%26display%3Dpage%26response_type%3Dcode%26perms%3Demail%252Cread_stream%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D345052285533166&rcount=1``

Comment: i'm sick off that. 

I don't understand Facebook coders.

if there is an offline_access & access_token subject, why do we need to login?

Comment: Also, HootSuite project (hootsuite.com) can post anything to my personal wall or my pages' wall. If it does, there is a solution for my problem. 

but what is it?

Comment: you probably better start with examples given in documentation

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled auto-posting is available when requesting the `publish_stream` permission, even when the user is actively using your application. From *[Permissions Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)*:

> **publish_stream**
>   Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends.
>   With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any
>   time. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated
>   sharing model. Please read the [Platform
>   Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) to ensure you
>   understand how to properly use this permission.